# How do I make sure I have enough gas for my transaction to go through. I get a value error whenever I try to deploy a contract in brownie

Tags: web3js, ganache, brownie, chainlink, visual-studio-code

I am following Patrick Alphas tutorial using brownie https://youtu.be/M576WGiDBdQ

. I have a fund_and_withdrawl script that has been compiled . With that, I am trying to deploy a fundme contract on a local ganache… Whenever I deploy a script, I get a value error telling me I don’t have enough ETH.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Are there any settings I should change. How high should my gas settings be ?

This is the FundMe.sol:

`````
~~~
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

// Smart contract that lets anyone deposit ETH into the contract
// Only the owner of the contract can withdraw the ETH
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

// Get the latest ETH/USD price from chainlink price feed
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";

contract FundMe {
    // safe math library check uint256 for integer overflows
    using SafeMathChainlink for uint256;
    
    //mapping to store which address depositeded how much ETH
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    // array of addresses who deposited
    address[] public funders;
    //address of the owner (who deployed the contract)
    address public owner;
    AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeed;
    
    // the first person to deploy the contract is
    // the owner
    constructor (address _priceFeed) public {  //#whatever parameter used will be our global price feed address
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeed);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function fund() public payable {
        // 18 digit number to be compared with donated amount 
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10 ** 18;
        //is the donated amount less than 50USD?
        require(getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD, "You need to spend more ETH!");
        //if not, add to mapping and funders array
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
    }
    
    //function to get the version of the chainlink pricefeed
    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
        //AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
       return priceFeed.version();  // above ...<-- we don't need this....we are doing it with a global address
    }
    
    function getPrice() public view returns(uint256){
        //AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
         // ETH/USD rate in 18 digit 
         return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
    }
    
    // 1000000000
    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount) public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1000000000000000000;
        // the actual ETH/USD conversation rate, after adjusting the extra 0s.
        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }
    function getEntranceFee() public view returns(uint256) {
        //minimu usd
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10**18;
        uint256 price = getPrice();
        uint256 precision = 1 *10*18 ;
        return (minimumUSD * precision) / price; 
    }
    //modifier: https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-tutorial-all-about-modifiers-a86cf81c14cb
    modifier onlyOwner {
        //is the message sender owner of the contract?
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        
        _;
    }
    
    // onlyOwner modifer will first check the condition inside it 
    // and 
    // if true, withdraw function will be executed 
    function withdraw() payable onlyOwner public {
    
        // If you are using version eight (v0.8) of chainlink aggregator interface,
    // you will need to change the code below to
    // payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);

        
        //iterate through all the mappings and make them 0
        //since all the deposited amount has been withdrawn
        for (uint256 funderIndex=0; funderIndex < funders.length; funderIndex++){
            address funder = funders[funderIndex];
            addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
        }
        //funders array will be initialized to 0
        funders = new address[](0);
    }
}
~~~~






#/#/Here is 
brownie config:/#/

~~~
dependencies:
  # - <organization/repo>@<version>
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - "@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1"
dotenv: .env
networks:
  rinkeby:
    eth_usd_price_feed: "0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e"
    verify: True
  development:
    verify: False
  ganache-local:
    verify: False 
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
~~~~

And here is fund_and_withdrawl.py:
~~~~~~




~~~~~~~~
from brownie import FundMe
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account 



def fund ():
    fund_me = FundMe[-1]
    account = get_account()
    entrance_fee = fund_me.getEntranceFee() 
    print(entrance_fee)
    print(f"The current entry fee is {entrance_fee}")
    print("Funding")
    fund_me.fund({"from": account, "value": entrance_fee})
    
    #always compile any edits to your solidity code  ...
    #need a main function always..
    
def main():
    fund()
~~~



And here is the .env file:

~~~~

export PRIVATE_KEY=0x1bb...............
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=76fc7f4e41ec4b398b9b590c000b2d87
export ETHERSCAN_TOKEN =6TXV8B4DBBSMGECPAI8AXDDC59EEE1K1WT
~~~



I got my helpful_scripts.py:

````from brownie import network, config, accounts, MockV3Aggregator
from web3 import Web3

LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS = [ "development", "ganache-local"]

DECIMALS = 8
STARTING_PRICE = 200000000000

def get_account():
    
    if network.show_active() in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
        return accounts[0]
    else:
        return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
    
    
def deploy_mocks():
    print(f"The active  network is { network.show_active() }")
    print("Deploying Mocks.....")
    if len(MockV3Aggregator) <= 0: #list of all v3 aggregators we've deployed
        MockV3Aggregator.deploy(DECIMALS , Web3.toWei(STARTING_PRICE,"ether"), {"from": get_account()})
    print("Mocks Deployed") #use tge most recently deployed mock agregator
`````

and lastly, the MockAgreggator.sol file:

''''

``````````
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV2V3Interface.sol";

/**
 * @title MockV3Aggregator
 * @notice Based on the FluxAggregator contract
 * @notice Use this contract when you need to test
 * other contract's ability to read data from an
 * aggregator contract, but how the aggregator got
 * its answer is unimportant
 */
contract MockV3Aggregator is AggregatorV2V3Interface {
  uint256 constant public override version = 0;

  uint8 public override decimals;
  int256 public override latestAnswer;
  uint256 public override latestTimestamp;
  uint256 public override latestRound;

  mapping(uint256 => int256) public override getAnswer;
  mapping(uint256 => uint256) public override getTimestamp;
  mapping(uint256 => uint256) private getStartedAt;

  constructor(
    uint8 _decimals,
    int256 _initialAnswer
  ) public {
    decimals = _decimals;
    updateAnswer(_initialAnswer);
  }

  function updateAnswer(
    int256 _answer
  ) public {
    latestAnswer = _answer;
    latestTimestamp = block.timestamp;
    latestRound++;
    getAnswer[latestRound] = _answer;
    getTimestamp[latestRound] = block.timestamp;
    getStartedAt[latestRound] = block.timestamp;
  }

  function updateRoundData(
    uint80 _roundId,
    int256 _answer,
    uint256 _timestamp,
    uint256 _startedAt
  ) public {
    latestRound = _roundId;
    latestAnswer = _answer;
    latestTimestamp = _timestamp;
    getAnswer[latestRound] = _answer;
    getTimestamp[latestRound] = _timestamp;
    getStartedAt[latestRound] = _startedAt;
  }

  function getRoundData(uint80 _roundId)
    external
    view
    override
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    )
  {
    return (
      _roundId,
      getAnswer[_roundId],
      getStartedAt[_roundId],
      getTimestamp[_roundId],
      _roundId
    );
  }

  function latestRoundData()
    external
    view
    override
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    )
  {
    return (
      uint80(latestRound),
      getAnswer[latestRound],
      getStartedAt[latestRound],
      getTimestamp[latestRound],
      uint80(latestRound)
    );
  }

  function description()
    external
    view
    override
    returns (string memory)
  {
    return "v0.6/tests/MockV3Aggregator.sol";
  }
}

// MockOracle
// Function signatures, event signatures, log topics
~~~~`````````
``````````

Comment: Could you please copy-paste the code as opposed to using a screenshot? This is hard to debug in it's current state.

Comment: Hi @Patrick Collins. I just copied and pasted my entire code from all  of my 6  files so far ...the formatting isn't the best, but I have left off at 5:40 on your video tutorial. I am learning as I go...

Comment: Hi @PatrickCollins . Is it also possible to change the gas parameters in brownie.ganache  like in the remix tutorial ? Maybe there is, but I haven't gotten far in your video,,,,

Comment: Hi Patrick. I got what I wanted : 
BrownieFundMeProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts/fund_and_withdrawl.py::main'...
25000000000000001
The current entry fee is 25000000000000001
Funding
Transaction sent: 0x05639dc31cda3273d2c810e7124d855260f7ff8f0389063488cc9820179af36a
  Gas price: 2.0 gwei   Gas limit: 99258   Nonce: 5
  FundMe.fund confirmed   Block: 6   Gas used: 90235 (90.91%)

Comment: I am scratching my head. I am not too  sure what I had input incorrectly...I guess my ganache accounts might not have had enough gas....

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I reset my ganache and restarted the contract calls. I also forgot to add this correction        `MockV3Aggregator.deploy(DECIMALS, STARTING_PRICE, {"from": get_account()})`
....

And I got what I wanted...